# PHP Include & CSS

Tags: php, html, css

In my website, I'd like to use the PHP include line within the index.php page to add in important sections like the header and footer.

Now, the folder structure is as follow:

/index.php

/css/style.css

/includes/header.php

/includes/footer.php

Keep in mind I am working in a localhost environment.

Now my question to you is how do I properly reference my CSS file in the index.php and header.php? Should I use a config.php file? I'd like to avoid using absolute paths if that's possible.

Currently, my CSS file is read and displays properly, however, when I make changes, the CSS does not display the changes made and keeps the original unchanged file.

**index.php**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <?php include 'includes/header.php';?>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <?php include 'includes/javascript.php';?>
    </div>
```

**header.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
      <div id="logo">
        <div class="logo-container">
          <img src="img/final_logo_400px.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
```

Comment: to `load` css files inside your web pages , you will need to use html's `<link />` tag, not php's include function;

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am well aware of this but thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a relative link no? ie:

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I presonally do the following which checks whether the file is local or remote, and versions the file using its modification time if it is remote (that check fails locally):

```
 $url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
 $parts = explode('/',$url);
 $base = $parts[0];
 if ($base == 'C:') { ?>
   <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <?php } else { ?>
   <link href="/css/style.css?v=<?php echo filemtime($basepath."/css/style.css")?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your response! Where would we place the php code above? In the index.php, header.php or a separate config.php file?

Comment: Well, technically (I am guessing!) any of those would work, but I suppose header.php would make most sense. Be aware this code is not "paste and go" it illustrates a concept of including a CSS file in a way that prevents caching issues.

Comment: ...just to add if you are relatively new to coding I would simply go with my first example... a standard relative link. It will need to be altered to reflect your directory structure.

Comment: See the thing is, with relative links, I can't seem to get the css to properly work when I modify the css styles. Maybe I should do an example on codepen or something.

Comment: After making changes do you refresh your browser without a cache? As in like, ctrl + f5?

Comment: Yep! I do. Still do not see changes.

Comment: You have href="css/style.css" whereas you very likely need a leading / as per my example. Although I see you do NOT have a slash on your php includes... are they working properly?

Comment: If I do that, the whole CSS stylesheet breaks. Yes the includes are showing up properly on the index.php file and when displayed in the browser.

Comment: OK, so you ARE including it properly, but you are not seeing changes? Put body {background: red !important} in it and tell me what happens when you refresh

Comment: Odd, that doesn't seem to change anything either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137793/discussion-between-colegauthier-and-mayersdesign).